Some questions about existence and uniqueness theorem
The solution of the ODE
$$y'-\frac{2}{x}y=0$$
is
$$y(x)=cx^2$$
for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. If $y(0)=0$, then
$$y(x)=0,\quad y(x)=x^2$$
are both solutions to the IVP. Why this doesn't contradict the existence and uniqueness theorem?
And since
$$y'=\frac{2}{x}y$$
then
$$f(x,y)=\frac{2y}{x}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{2}{x}$$
i.e., $f_{y}(x,y)$ is not continuous at $x=0$. So, how can I still find a solution at $x=0$?

Who said to you that a first order linear ODE can't have two solutions?

That's my question. "Why this doesn't contradict the existence and uniqueness theorem?"

Ok I think I interpreted your question incorrectly...let me again have a look at it

$y(0)=0$ cannot be an initial value condition for the given equation, because the differential equation is only valid for $x\neq0$. If you rewrite it as $xy^\prime-2y=0$ then it makes sense, but then the uniqueness condition is only for equations of the kind $y^\prime=f(x,y)$.
Hope this helps. :)

Then, as the equation is not $y'=f(x,y)$, we can't apply the uniqueness theorem and that's why it has two different solutions?

@mvfs314: yeah, for the differential equation I mentioned, that is right.
